# Proper syntax for mapping font style from object map to map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

React, JS, and Material UI

Ok, probably a noob question, but what the hell am I doing wrong with my syntax in my style property in my map function?

Fonts.jsx

```
export const fonts = [
  {
    fontName: 'Abril',
    key: 'abril',
    fontFamily: "'Abril Fatface', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Bangers',
    key: 'bangers',
    fontFamily: "'Bangers', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Bebas',
    key: 'bebas',
    fontFamily: "'Bebas Neue', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Bungee',
    key: 'bungee',
    fontFamily: "'Bungee', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Dancing',
    key: 'dancing',
    fontFamily: "'Dancing Script', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Fascinate',
    key: 'fascinate',
    fontFamily: "'Fascinate', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Frijole',
    key: 'frijole',
    fontFamily: "'Frijole', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Girassol',
    key: 'girassol',
    fontFamily: "'Girassol', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Goblin',
    key: 'goblin',
    fontFamily: "'Goblin One', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Graduate',
    key: 'graduate',
    fontFamily: "'Graduate', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Great Vibes',
    key: 'greatVibes',
    fontFamily: "'Great Vibes', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Shadows',
    key: 'shadows',
    fontFamily: "'Shadows Into Light', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Krona',
    key: 'Krona',
    fontFamily: "'Krona One', sans-serif;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Lobster',
    key: 'Lobster',
    fontFamily: "'Lobster', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Newsreader',
    key: 'newsreader',
    fontFamily: "'Newsreader', serif;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Permanent Marker',
    key: 'permanentMarker',
    fontFamily: "'Permanent Marker', cursive;",
  },
  {
    fontName: 'Righteous',
    key: 'righteous',
    fontFamily: "'Righteous', cursive;",
  },
  { fontName: 'Spartan', key: 'spartan', fontFamily: "'Spartan', sans-serif;" },
];
```

and my map() function:

```
<Select label="Font" onChange={handleFont} defaultValue="Abril" className={classes.selectEmpty} value={font}>                
  {fonts.map((el, i) => (
     <MenuItem key={el.key} value={el.fontName} style={{ fontFamily: el.fontFamily }}>
        {el.fontName}
     </MenuItem>))}
</Select>
```

Errors I'm getting are this:
Warning: Style property values shouldn't contain a semicolon. Try "fontFamily: 'Spartan', sans-serif" instead.

I think I know what I need to do, but not how to do it.  Any help for a struggling noob that spent waaaaaay too much time on this already?

Comment: If the warning says that you shouldn't add a semicolon, you should try removing the semicolons from the `fontFamily` strings.

Comment: omg......I feel like an idiot.  Yes, that did it.  Thanks for saving me from pulling my hair out :)

Answer (score 1):

iz_ helped answer my silly question in the comments.  thanks bud.

Removing the ; from my objects did the trick